# Rails 3 - How to Create a JSON Object to store in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm creating an AuditLog observer that watches over several models.

I'd like the observer to have an after_create, which creates a JSON object that is stored in a database column. It will contain data like {photoid:123, photoname: "asdasd", creator_id: "asdasd"} etc...

In Rails, how do I create this type of JSON object and then how do I insert it into the DB along with other non-JSON fields?

Thanks

Answer (score 64):

Current versions of rails support json serialisation out of the box. Define your field as a string (or text) in the migration and then:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :field, JSON
end

bar = Foo.new
bar.field = [1,2,3]
bar.save
```

Comment: Might be better to define it as text, otherwise the 255 character limit may cause problems.

Comment: If this isn't working for some reason (still seeing things like `{\"abc\":\"123\"}` when the record is jsonified) , what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 10):

First, definitely check out ActiveRecord serialize and see if it does what you need: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-serialize

However, if you need JSON specifically (serialize uses YAML by default), then you can always fake it by hand.

You can simply build a hash in Ruby and then call `to_json` on it before assigning it to your model attribute.

```
data = { 'photoid' => 123, 'photoname' => "asdasd", 'creator_id' => "asdasd" }
myrecord.stored_data = data.to_json
myrecord.save
```

Comment: Is to_json safe? I've seen some posts on Google Searches that mention it sometimes fails? Any thoughts on that?

Comment: There are some wrinkles when you're using `to_json` on an activerecord object (you're supposed to use `as_json` or something), but for serializing a simple hash it's really straightforward JSON encoding... not much to go wrong. What did you find with Google?

Comment: What is the myrecord.stored_data all about ? (stored_data)?

Comment: Turns out the above doesn't work...getting errors on "stored_data" does not exist... Also, should the observer be in the CONTROLLERS or MODELS Directory? bec running the generator put it in the models dir.

Comment: "undefined method `save' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: Getting: "undefined method `data=' for nil:NilClass" when I try this:     data = { 'photoid' => 123, 'photoname' => "This is my photo", 'creator_id' => "1" }
    @AuditLog.data = data.to_json
    @AuditLog.save

Comment: `stored_data` is an example attribute name. It can be anything you want. It also has to be backed by a text column in your database... it's not magic. Create a migration to add it.

Answer (score -3):

Take a look at this: http://github.com/laserlemon/vestal_versions

If it's not what you're looking for, it will at least show you it's done.

Comment: The auditlog is just an example to make the question easier to digest... Thanks though.