# how to get value from a field in table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have a field named 'parameter' in table with below format

```
utf8: "\xE2\x9C\x93"
id: "805265"
plan: initial
acc: "123456"
last: "1234"
doc: "1281468479"
validation: field
commit: Accept
```

how to query 'acc' value from the table?

database :sequelPro

Comment: Is that just a text area?

Comment: When you save into parameter you should save as a json. Then you can search a json object

Comment: yes it is just text area with above format

Comment: Could you save it as a json object?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/24463973/1380867

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/a/10870259/1380867

Comment: i cant save it as a json object. i need to save this value into another field

Answer (score 1):

```
> str = 'utf8..... your string here...'
> puts str
utf8: "\xE2\x9C\x93"
id: "805265"
plan: initial
acc: "123456"
last: "1234"
doc: "1281468479"
validation: field
commit: Accept
=> nil
> str.match(/^acc: "(\d+)"/).captures.first
=> "123456"
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, In  `PostgreSQL` use [**split_part**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-string.html)

See this EXAMPLE

```
create table star (param text);
insert into star values ('utf8: "\xE2\x9C\x93"'),
                        ('id: "805265"'),
                        ('plan: initial'),
                        ('acc: "123456"'),
                        ('last: "1234"'),
                        ('doc: "1281468479"'),
                        ('validation: field'),
                        ('commit: Accept');
```

and use function `split_part` in *SELECT* query to get value of `acc:` like this

```
select col2 
from (
      select split_part(param, ' ', 1) col1,
             split_part(param, ' ', 2) col2 
      from star
     ) t where col1='acc:'
```

Note: if you want to split your field by `:` then use `select split_part(param, ':', 1)` and `split_part(param, ':', 2) col2`  so the *WHERE* clause should be `where col1='acc'`

[**sqlfiddle-demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2cd74/1/0)

Comment: @jack I've created table just for an **example** no need to create table in your case :D(_you already have the table with data but think in my case i dont have any table or data like your's so i need to create one to test right ?_), just query like I've described in my answer

Comment: @jack  `select col2 
from (
      select split_part(_YOUR_COLUMN/FIELD_, ':', 1) col1,
             split_part(_YOUR_COLUMN/FIELD_, ':', 2) col2 
      from _YOUR_TABLE_NAME_
     )t where col1='acc' `

Comment: my database doesn't support split_part

Comment: @jack what's your DB and It's version ?